# Android Add Delay in onDraw method

Tags: android, delay, ondraw

I am new to android and building an app which involves displaying a view for 2 seconds and then change. Here's my onDraw method:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
float level = game.level;
width = getWidth();
tile_length = width/level;

Paint rect = new Paint();
rect.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dark));
canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, width, rect);

   game.numbers.setTextSize( (0.70f * tile_length));
   game.numbers.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

   grid.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.lines));
  rect.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tile_on));

   int ind = 1;
   int tile_num = 1;
   FontMetrics fm = game.numbers.getFontMetrics();  

 float x = tile_length/2;
   float y = tile_length/2 - (fm.ascent + fm.descent) / 2;

   Log.v(LOG_TAG, "changed = " + game.changed);

  for (int i=0; i<width; i+=tile_length)
  {
  for(int j=0; j<width; j+=tile_length)
  {
  for(int k = 0; k<level; k++ )
  if(tile_num == game.random[k])
  {
//   Log.v(LOG_TAG, "i = " + i + "j = " + j);
 game.set_Coordinates(ind-1, i, j);
 String tile = Integer.toString(ind++);
 canvas.drawRect(i, j, i+tile_length, j+tile_length, rect);
 canvas.drawText(tile, i+x, j+y, game.numbers); //needs to be updated after 2 seconds
  break;
  }

  tile_num++;

  }
  }
    }
```

I understand i have to use postdelayed method somewhere, but don't know how...Now i just want to ommit the canvas.drawText line after the delay.

Comment: What is the change that you want to do after 2 seconds? Please explain

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like this

```java
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
  public void run(){
    // do something here like draw text;
 }
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

A timer is needed, indeed. What I do, which is very simple, is first to create **records** of coordinates (and any other data needed) for every point of the drawing -- instead of drawing the points on the spot -- and then reproduce them using a timer (Android handler, preferably, like the one suggested above). This also offers you a lot of possibilities while actual drawing: pause, go faster/slower, go backwards, ...
I don't know if this method can be used for complicated drawings, but it is fine for drawing shapes, curves, surfaces, etc.